# C: Error allocating memory on ADT 1 class

Tags: c, pointers, adt

i'm having trouble with a ADT 1 class.
I'm trying to initializing a vector of pointer to a struct, but something doesn't work

Inside Divisione.h i had:

`typedef struct divisione_t *divisione_s;`

In Divisione.c we can find:

```
#define DEP 4

typedef struct{
    int ndip, smin, sott;
}Req;

 typedef struct{
    char *code;
    Req *r;
}divisione_t;

static Req InitReq();

divisione_s *InitDiv(int ndiv){
    divisione_s *div;

    div = (divisione_s *) calloc(ndiv, sizeof(*div));
    if(div == NULL)
        exit(-1);

    for(int i=0; i<ndiv; i++){
        div[i]->r = (Req *) calloc(DEP, sizeof(Req));
        if(div[i]->r == NULL)
            exit(-1);

        for(int j=0; j<DEP; j++)
            div[i]->r[j] = InitReq();
    }

}

static Req InitReq(){
    Req r;
    r.ndip = -1;
    r.smin = -1; 
    r.sott = -1;
    return r;
}
```

The error is on line:
`div[i]->r = (Req *) calloc(DEP, sizeof(Req));`
and it say
"error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct divisione_t"

thanks in advance if anything other is needed tell me

Comment: It's just a boring typo. `divisione_s` is not `divisione_t`. Which the code color formatting should have hinted at.

Comment: `typedef struct divisione_t *divisione_s;` There is no `struct divisione_t` type shown. Note that `typedef struct { .. } divisione_t;` makes a type called `divisione_t` not `struct divisione_t`.

Comment: @kaylum i modified `typedef struct { .. } divisione_t;` to struct divisione_t{ .. } and now the compiler doesn't show the error anymore. But the program is still not running...
 I tried to change the allocation of Req *r into static but when i try to debugged it crashes on the initialization to -1 of the value in `div[i]->r[j].variables  = -1;`
any idea that can help me?